# begin() vs rbegin() how they are implemented?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

In the following image I'm using the same type of iterators which means the same implementation of operator++ so how does the compiler know if it should get the next value or the previous one...?

[image]

Comment: The `operator++` overload is different for regular and reverse iterators. Just like you can overload `++` to do completely different things for two different classes. Try to implement an overload of `++` for some class that does what you would expect `--` to do, instead. Once you complete this task, the answer to your question should be very obvious to you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik but the iterator in the same, there is no regular and reverse iterator, all are vector<int>::iterator

Comment: If you actually tried it, you'd notice that it won't compile :-)

Comment: This is a mistake in your textbook. [rbegin() and rend() do NOT return `iterator`s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin). They return a `reverse_iterator`, a completely different class. Whichever textbook you got it from, throw it away and get a better textbook.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik should I tell my professor :-)

Comment: It's funny that it's one of the best universities in the field of CS in the world  LOL

Comment: @SamVarshavchik do you work in the field of Cyber security testing?

Comment: C++ is hard to get right on paper. There are tons of bugs in even the best C++ resources. Sometimes the inaccuracies are caused by the author wanting to simplify the code in order to focus the attention on a specific aspect. Like if they used `auto`, that would solve the issue but might arguably make the code harder to understand. Note: there is a curated list of C++ resources available here: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Anything outside it should be taken with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 2):

First, the picture you have contains an error. As you can see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) the reverse iterator type of vector is `std::reverse_iterator<iterator>` which uses the template [`std::reverse_iterator<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator). So `begin` and `rbegin` have not the same return value (and I also do not think they are convertible to each other).

But actually that wouldn't even be a problem, you could implement

```
struct iter {
    bool reverse;
    pointer ptr;
 
    iter& operator++() {
        if(reverse) --ptr;
        else ++ptr;
        return *this;
     }
};
```

But type-seperating them is really preferable.

Comment: As a note, reverse_iterator generally _is_ convertible to iterator, but not the other way. For example: std::vector<int> v; auto rit {v.rbegin() }; auto it {rit}; compiled without complaint. Makes sense as reverse_iterator has the base() member which returns the corresponding iterator.

Comment: That does only compile because you use auto and hence `it` is just a copy of `rit` and also a reverse iterator. Take `std::vector<int>:: iterator it{rit};` and it will not compile. There are good reasons to not let iterators and reverse iterators mingle implicitly, e.g. `std::distance` would be weird, since it had to be the same in both directions which is counterintuitive.